# Getting impossible to create a new session while trying to invoke chrome browser from an android emulator present in Saucelabs?

Tags: java, selenium, android-emulator, saucelabs

I am working on automating Android Mobile Browser using saucelabs.
I am trying to invoke mobile emulator device from saucelabs but getting the below error message:

**It is impossible to create a new session because 'createSession' which takes HttpClient, InputStream and long was not found or it is not accessible**

Below is my desired capabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.9.1");
caps.setCapability("deviceName", PropertyReader.readProperty("DEVICE")+" GoogleAPI Emulator");
caps.setCapability("deviceOrientation", "portrait");
caps.setCapability("browserName", "Chrome");
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
String SAUCE_REMOTE_URL = PropertyReader.readProperty("SAUCE_LABS_AUTH");
URL url = new URL(SAUCE_REMOTE_URL);
mobileDriver.set(new AndroidDriver(url, caps));
```

Could any one please guide me to understand what exactly the issue is??
Have attached screenshots of Configuration and error message from console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3dEa.png)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons could be that you're referring to an old version of Appium in your capabilities

`caps.setCapability("appiumVersion", "1.9.1");`

As far as I know Android 8.1 doesn't work (properly) with that version of Appium. Best thing is to use a newer one, this can be found [here](https://saucelabs.com/platform/platform-configurator#/)

If this doesn't help then please contact the helpdesk of Sauce, they can guide you to make this work.